# Align text to bottom of a frame using Core Text

Tags: c, core-text

I have an attributed string that I want to draw bottom-aligned into a rectangular path, using Core Text. Is there a way to get CTFrameSetter / CTFrame to do this, or do I need to do it manually? The manual way being:

1. Figure out the height of the frame using CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints
2. Adjust the height of the path.

Comment: I thought the Core Text APIs were only available i C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do it manually.

```
CGRect boundingBox = CTFontGetBoundingBox(font);

//Get the position on the y axis
float midHeight = self.frame.size.height / 2;
midHeight -= boundingBox.size.height / 2;

CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0, midHeight, self.frame.size.width, boundingBox.size.height));
```

Reference: [Vertical align with Core Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284326/vertical-align-with-core-text)

Comment: What if you use multiple fonts?

Comment: I can't understand how you make it work. 
is `path` the path used to draw the frame? how can it work with multiple lines? isn't the boundingbox calculated for a single line?