# How to move CGMutablePathRef?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, core-text

I have a snippet of code below that draws a string to a `UIView` using `CoreText`:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)self.text);
    CGMutablePathRef mutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(mutablePathRef, NULL, self.bounds);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), mutablePathRef, NULL);

    CGFloat frameHeight = [self calculateHeightForFrame: frameRef];

    //what do I do here to resposition the mutablePathRef?

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, context); 

    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CGPathRelease(mutablePathRef);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
}
```

I initialize a frame and frame setter, and attach them to a `CGMutablePath`. Then I use the `CTLine` origins from the frame to calculate the height of the text so I can center it vertically.

After this point I'm a little stumped. Is there a way to move the position of the `CGMutablePath` to a new origin so it will be centered vertically? I tried `CGPathMoveToPoint` and it didn't work.

Or do I need to create a brand new `CGMutablePath` and a brand new frame and frame setter? If so, how do I remove the `CGMutablePath`? Will it be removed if I release it?

Any hints on an efficient way I could solve this would be great, thanks.

Comment: ultimately, I had to create a frameRef to determine the height, then I had to recreate the frameRef and reposition it in the center based on the height I calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your `CGMutablePathRef` has been used to create the frame, modifying the path has not effect on the frame. Moreover `CGPathMoveToPoint` doesn't move the path itself but is current point, allowing the append new subpaths.

You can change the position of the text by applying a translation on the context before drawing.

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3284326/937822) shows how to vertically center text with Core Text.

Basically, you need to determine the height of the text and modify your path before you call CGPathAddRect().