# Core Text - Vertical align (With multiple lines)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-text

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284326/vertical-align-with-core-text) I understood how to vertical align a text of a single line:

```
CGRect boundingBox = CTFontGetBoundingBox(font);

//Get the position on the y axis
float midHeight = self.frame.size.height / 2;
midHeight -= boundingBox.size.height / 2;

CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0, midHeight, self.frame.size.width, boundingBox.size.height));
```

But this code works only for a single line context. When the frame generates a multiple line string (with soft or hard line break) that code doesn't work.

Comment: What type is `self.frame`?

Comment: It seems to me that if we assume `self.frame.size` to be the enclosing rectangle of the text in question, then it shouldn't matter whether there is one line, or whether there are many; `self.frame.size.height / 2` will still provide the mid-line.  Is my assumption faulty?  What effect does your code actually have?